# declare-styleable. Specify that an attribute is absolutely required

Tags: android

Is there a way to specify that an attribute is absolutely required inside the `xml` ? Something similar to an annotation ... so that when the user uses the custom view, the `IDE` will notify him that he has missed an importantt attribute.

Currently I'm validating the attributes during run-time and throw an exception if he has missed one. I was wondering if there's another way of going about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the `<attr>` element accepts a `required` attribute. However, if your goal is to alert the developer in the IDE of a missing required attribute, you can instead check the value of `isInEditMode()` ([doc reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode())) and provide a detailed error message there which will be displayed for example in the visual editor.

In fact, the runtime exception that you are throwing should also already be displayed in the visual editor of the IDE - however you could use `isInEditMode()` to customize the error message.

Admittedly, this is a far-from-perfect solution. There are times when it is impractical to use the visual editor to edit a custom view. There are cases when the `<declare-styleable>` is used for non-visual purposes.